# Vanilla Forums Facebook Authentication Error: UniqueID is required

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, vanilla-forums

Recently my instance of Vanilla Forums stoped authenticating users via Facebook. Instead, the error message "UniqueID is required" is shown in the authentication page.

[image: Vanilla Forums error "UniqueID is required"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found this [blog post](http://nutmedia.co.uk/snippets/vanilla-forums-facebook-login-uniqueid-required-issue-fix/), this [github issue](https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla/issues/5381) and this [pull request](https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla/pull/5371/files#diff-fa8689b808080a1456afb013beefca68R486).

For now I fixed the function `getAccessToken()` replacing this:

```
    if (strpos(val('content_type', $Info, ''), '/javascript') !== false) {
        $Tokens = json_decode($Contents, true);
    } else {
        parse_str($Contents, $Tokens);
    }
```

with this:

```
    if (strpos(val('content_type', $Info, ''), '/javascript') !== false) {
        $Tokens = json_decode($Contents, true);
    } else if (strpos(val('content_type', $Info, ''), '/json') !== false) {
        $Tokens = json_decode($Contents, true);
    } else {
        parse_str($Contents, $Tokens);
    }
```

Since the Pull Request was merged a few days ago, the next release should fix this.

Comment: This fixes it, thanks. Simply the format in which the data is returned from FB.